# Can't get Input from EditText inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, localhost

I am making an app that can show different product images and there is a button to choose them and this button will send the info to `localhost`.

But, `EditText` is not working. If I do

```
ItemNote=(EditText) imageLayout.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ItemNote);
```

it will work but only for that option and again stop working for different options.

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
        assert imageLayout != null;

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);

         ItemNote=(EditText) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.ItemNote);
         ItemQuantity=(EditText)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.ItemQuantity);

         ItemName=(TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
         ItemPrice=(TextView)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.ItemPrice);

         choose=(Button) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.choose);
            quantity=ItemQuantity.getText().toString();
            note=ItemNote.getText().toString();
            name=ItemName.getText().toString();
            price=ItemPrice.getText().toString();
         choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //getting input for item quantity and Item Extraa note
                String Order= " "+name+" "+'('+quantity+')'+" With "+note+" Price : "+price+'\n';
                ItemNote.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
                ItemQuantity.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
                messsage = Order; // get the text message on the text field
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the note inside of onClick. Currently you're reading the text in instantiateItem so it's only getting the text when that method is called. You need to get the text at the time the button is clicked.